# Xilinx Zynq7k linux, ошибка при компиляции u-boot

Tags: linux, makefile, кросс-компиляция

Всем привет!
Получают следующие ошибки при компиляции u-boot (SoC Zynq7k 020)

```
cc1: error: bad value (‘generic-armv7-a’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake tigerlake cooperlake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 znver3 btver1 btver2 generic native
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:155: lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: error: bad value (‘generic-armv7-a’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake tigerlake cooperlake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 znver3 btver1 btver2 generic native
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:155: arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1841: prepare0] Error 2
```

Что делал.

1. Установил зависимости `sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf u-boot-tools build-essential -y`
2. Клонировал репо `git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git`
3. Перешел в репо `cd u-boot-xln`
   4.0 Создал build_ub и наполнил скрипт содержимим:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
export ARCH=arm
make distclean
make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig
export DEVICE_TREE="zynq"
```

4.1 Сделал его исполняемым командой chmod +x

5.0 Скопировал zynq.dts в папку  `u-boot-xln/arch/arm/dts/`

5.1 ./build_ub
получил такой лог

```
  CLEAN   spl/u-boot.cfg
  CLEAN   u-boot.cfg u-boot.cfg.configs
  CLEAN   scripts/basic
  CLEAN   scripts/dtc
  CLEAN   scripts/kconfig
  CLEAN   include/config include/generated spl
  CLEAN   .config .config.old include/autoconf.mk include/autoconf.mk.dep include/config.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

6. make -j
   Получаю ошибки

```
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make -j
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
  CFG     spl/u-boot.cfg
  GEN     spl/include/autoconf.mk
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
  UPD     include/generated/dt.h
  CFGCHK  u-boot.cfg
  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/checks.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/util.o
  LEX     scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.h
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
  UPD     include/config/uboot.release
  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
  CC      arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s
cc1: error: bad value (‘generic-armv7-a’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake tigerlake cooperlake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 znver3 btver1 btver2 generic native
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:155: lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: error: bad value (‘generic-armv7-a’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake tigerlake cooperlake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 znver3 btver1 btver2 generic native
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:155: arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1841: prepare0] Error 2
```

UPD.

Сделал по другому. Все шаги прошел руками (в соответствии с [мануалом](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841973/Build+U-Boot#BuildU-Boot-U-bootbuildsteps)). Все сделал с чистого листа.
Что сделал:

1. `git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git`
2. `cd u-boot-xlnx/`
3. `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`
4. `export ARCH=arm`
5. `make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig`
6. `export DEVICE_TREE="zynq-zturn"`  // взял devicetree, которое шло с u-boot.
7. `make`

Получил другую ошибку:
`fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory`

Вывод консоли:

```
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git
Cloning into 'u-boot-xlnx'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 775761, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2071/2071), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (868/868), done.
remote: Total 775761 (delta 1400), reused 1728 (delta 1193), pack-reused 773690
Receiving objects: 100% (775761/775761), 179.31 MiB | 9.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (636538/636538), done.
Updating files: 100% (17628/17628), done.
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ cd u-boot-xlnx/
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export ARCH=arm
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export DEVICE_TREE="zynq-zturn"
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
  CFG     spl/u-boot.cfg
  GEN     spl/include/autoconf.mk
  UPD     include/config/uboot.release
  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  UPD     include/generated/dt.h
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h
  CC      arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/checks.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/util.o
  LEX     scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
  HOSTCC  tools/envcrc.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/crc32.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/crc32.o
  WRAP    tools/env/embedded.c
  HOSTCC  tools/env/embedded.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/sha1.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/sha1.o
  HOSTLD  tools/envcrc
  HOSTCC  tools/gen_eth_addr
  HOSTCC  tools/gen_ethaddr_crc.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/crc8.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/crc8.o
  HOSTLD  tools/gen_ethaddr_crc
  HOSTCC  tools/img2srec
  HOSTCC  tools/mkenvimage.o
  HOSTCC  tools/os_support.o
  HOSTLD  tools/mkenvimage
  HOSTCC  tools/aisimage.o
In file included from tools/aisimage.c:9:
include/image.h:1222:12: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 1222 | #  include <openssl/evp.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:112: tools/aisimage.o] Error 1
```

8. Решил проверить, какой по-факту компилятор используется. `make V=1` получил следующий лог

```
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make V=1
set -e; mkdir -p include/config/;   echo "2021.01$(/bin/bash ./scripts/setlocalversion .)" < include/config/auto.conf > include/config/uboot.release.tmp; if [ -r include/config/uboot.release ] && cmp -s include/config/uboot.release include/config/uboot.release.tmp; then rm -f include/config/uboot.release.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/config/uboot.release'; mv -f include/config/uboot.release.tmp include/config/uboot.release; fi
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/;    (echo \#define PLAIN_VERSION \"2021.01""-00051-g88cb3bc3f9\"; echo \#define U_BOOT_VERSION \"U-Boot \" PLAIN_VERSION; echo \#define CC_VERSION_STRING \"$(LC_ALL=C arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version | head -n 1)\"; echo \#define LD_VERSION_STRING \"$(LC_ALL=C arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.bfd --version | head -n 1)\"; ) < include/config/uboot.release > include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/version_autogenerated.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/version_autogenerated.h include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h'; mv -f include/generated/version_autogenerated.h.tmp include/generated/version_autogenerated.h; fi
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/;    (if test -n "${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}"; then SOURCE_DATE="@${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH}"; DATE=""; for date in gdate date.gnu date; do ${date} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" >/dev/null 2>&1 && DATE="${date}"; done; if test -n "${DATE}"; then LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_DATE "%b %d %C%y"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_TIME "%T"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_TZ "%z"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_DMI_DATE "%m/%d/%Y"'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_BUILD_DATE 0x%Y%m%d'; LC_ALL=C ${DATE} -u -d "${SOURCE_DATE}" +'#define U_BOOT_EPOCH %s'; else return 42; fi; else LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_DATE "%b %d %C%y"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_TIME "%T"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_TZ "%z"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_DMI_DATE "%m/%d/%Y"'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_BUILD_DATE 0x%Y%m%d'; LC_ALL=C date +'#define U_BOOT_EPOCH %s'; fi) < Makefile > include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h'; mv -f include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h.tmp include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h; fi
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/;    (if test -n "${DEVICE_TREE}"; then echo \#define DEVICE_TREE \"zynq-zc702\"; else echo \#define DEVICE_TREE CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE; fi) < Makefile > include/generated/dt.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/dt.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/dt.h include/generated/dt.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/dt.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/dt.h'; mv -f include/generated/dt.h.tmp include/generated/dt.h; fi
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=.
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/;    (set -e; echo "#ifndef __GENERIC_ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "#define __GENERIC_ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "/*"; echo " * DO NOT MODIFY."; echo " *"; echo " * This file was generated by Kbuild"; echo " */"; echo ""; sed -ne  "s:[[:space:]]*\.ascii[[:space:]]*\"\(.*\)\":\1:; /^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:->::; p;}"; echo ""; echo "#endif" ) < lib/asm-offsets.s > include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h'; mv -f include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h.tmp include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h; fi
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/;    (set -e; echo "#ifndef __ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "#define __ASM_OFFSETS_H__"; echo "/*"; echo " * DO NOT MODIFY."; echo " *"; echo " * This file was generated by Kbuild"; echo " */"; echo ""; sed -ne  "s:[[:space:]]*\.ascii[[:space:]]*\"\(.*\)\":\1:; /^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:->::; p;}"; echo ""; echo "#endif" ) < arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s > include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/asm-offsets.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/asm-offsets.h include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h'; mv -f include/generated/asm-offsets.h.tmp include/generated/asm-offsets.h; fi
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/dtc
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=tools
  cc -Wp,-MD,tools/.mkenvimage.o.d -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -std=gnu11   -DCONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE -DCONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE_MAX_SIZE=0x10000000 -include ./include/compiler.h -idirafterinclude -idirafter./arch/arm/include -I./scripts/dtc/libfdt -I./tools -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99  -c -o tools/mkenvimage.o tools/mkenvimage.c
  cc   -o tools/mkenvimage tools/mkenvimage.o tools/os_support.o tools/lib/crc32.o   
  cc -Wp,-MD,tools/.aisimage.o.d -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -std=gnu11   -DCONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE -DCONFIG_FIT_SIGNATURE_MAX_SIZE=0x10000000 -include ./include/compiler.h -idirafterinclude -idirafter./arch/arm/include -I./scripts/dtc/libfdt -I./tools -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99  -c -o tools/aisimage.o tools/aisimage.c
In file included from tools/aisimage.c:9:
include/image.h:1222:12: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 1222 | #  include <openssl/evp.h>
```

Почему возникает эта ошибка? Я использую стандартный device_tree (поставляется с u-boot), копмилятор, вроде, что нужно используется... Все шаги в соответствии с мануалом, но не работает. Может мне нужно установить какие-либо дополнительные программы?

Comment: дык, а свой `build_ub` ты `source`'нул? и зачем ты в него команды конфигурации включил?  ЗЫ: текст лучше приводить текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: Про картинку понял. Я его сделал chmod +x

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы вызвана тем, что, по факту, не задан кросс компилятор; в результате системе сборки вместо кросскомпилятора `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` вызывает просто компилятор хост-системы (`gcc`). Это было бы более очевидно, если запустить `make` с параметром `make V=1`

---

> 3.Перешел в репо cd u-boot-xln 4.0 Создал build_ub и наполнил скрипт содержимим:
>
> ```
> export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
> export ARCH=arm
> make distclean
> make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig
> export DEVICE_TREE="zynq"
> ```
>
> ....
> 5.1 ./build_ub получил такой лог

Экспортировать переменные надо непосредственно в той оболочке, в которой запускаются команды, которые будут их использовать. т.е.
`export CROSS_COMPILE=...` надо делать вручную. Если же их всё же помещать в скрипт, то, во-первых, в него не стоит добавлять ни каких конкретных действий (`my.env`):

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
export ARCH=arm
export DEVICE_TREE="zynq"
```

И во-вторых, переменные из него нужно импортировать в среду с помощью команды `source` (синоним `.`):

```
$ source my.env
```

`make distclean` и `make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig` нужно выполнять вручную по мере необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы:
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`